# Disable “Add to home screen” if native App with TWA (Trusted Web Activities) is installed

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, twa

Initial situation:
I installed a native app with a TWA on my Android phone that opens lets say "www.example.com" and I was able to turn off the app installation prompt with the instructions here. https://web.dev/get-installed-related-apps/#check-android (Add related_application to manifest)

Now when I open the Google Chrome browser on Android and enter the URL "www.example.com", then there is no more installation prompt popup but when I go to the three dots its still possible to click “Add to Home screen” and then the PWA is installed as webapk.[Add to homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bfXy.jpg)

Now my question is it possible to disable this option or have the same behaviour as for an installed PWA (as described below)?

PWA behaviour:

1. Go to "www.example.com"
2. 3 dots, Install app [Install app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyON1.jpg)
3. If webapk is installed on the device, again go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
4. Go to the three dots, then you see open PWA, and it is not possible to install the PWA again.[Open PWA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP6yM.jpg)

Can I have this behaviour when I install the PWA as a native app with TWA? TWA generation happens with bubblewrap (https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap)

Comment: To clarify my understanding: 1 - The TWA application is installed on the user's device (A2H doesn't show inside the TWA and the 3 dots menu is hidden). 2 - The A2H prompt has been disabled when using the PWA from the browser. 3 - But it's still possible to install the webapk using the 3 dots menu, and you'd like to disable that. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to prevent the user from trying to install from the 3-dot menu. If you'd like, head over to https://new.crbug.com to file a feature request and we can take a look at it.